# capturing the icon menu left mouse click in console application

Tags: menu, icons, console-application

I am attempting to utilize the console window's icon menu within my console application. I have figured out how to add the menu items I want to the console window's icon menu by googling how to do that. What I am having trouble with is attaching handlers to the items that I have added. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is a small program that I am using to test the theory:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace testnotify
{
    enum CtrlTypes : uint
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool InsertMenu(IntPtr hMenu,
            Int32 wPosition, Int32 wFlags, Int32 wIDNewItem,
            string lpNewItem);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegate HandlerRoutine, bool Add);

        delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrlDelegate(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

        public const Int32 WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        public const Int32 MF_SEPARATOR = 0x800;
        public const Int32 MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;
        public const Int32 MF_STRING = 0x0;
        public const Int32 IDM_CUSTOMITEM1 = 1000;
        public const Int32 IDM_CUSTOMITEM2 = 1001;

        static bool is_attached = false;

        // this handles the exiting Close menu item click
        static ConsoleCtrlDelegate ConsoleCtrlDelegateDetach = delegate (CtrlTypes ctrlType)
        {
            if (is_attached = !FreeConsole())
                Trace.TraceError("FreeConsole on " + ctrlType + ": " + new Win32Exception());
            return true;
        };

        // this is where I would provide handlers for the menu items added to the console's icon menu

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr sysMenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, false);

            InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 5, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_SEPARATOR, 0, string.Empty);
            InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 6, MF_BYPOSITION, IDM_CUSTOMITEM1, "Item 1");
            InsertMenu(sysMenuHandle, 7, MF_BYPOSITION, IDM_CUSTOMITEM2, "Item 2");

            // I need to add code here to set up handlers for the item1 and item2 menu items I have added

            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegateDetach, true);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```